# Opening Plugin with another Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I would like to open a Plugin with the help of another Plugin.

Is it possible, if I want to switch the workflow of different plugins one after the other, that when I click the submit button of one plugin I close this plugin and another one opens automatically?

Comment: Do you have some code to show? Are those Plugins written by yourself or your intended to use some existing Plugins?

Comment: I dont think the code would help. It's just two plugins I wrote on myself and I want to open the second plugin when pressing the "OK"-button of the first one.

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: ok thanks. and how can I manage this ?

Comment: When QGIS starts, it loads plugins as python modules. So, in your plugin, just create a method / function with `import my_second_plugin` and start it.

Comment: thanks I am gonna try this solution later; after the import, how do I start the plugin then with code ?

Comment: Just start your plugin as the method / function connected to the menu icon does.

Comment: can you give me an example ? I dont think that I am understanding you correctly. Thank you !

Comment: How can I run a plugin I developed myself (with plugin builder) with a python code ? Which method/function do I need to call for startup?

Comment: Is there a `run` method in the second plugin?

Comment: yes there is a run method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For my example, I took the QGIS plugin **Plugin Builder 3** ([link](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder3/)).

After install of this plugin, a new repository is made in :

`\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\pluginbuilder3`

(here is the default profile `default`, it can be an other).

If you look in the `__init__.py` :

```py
def classFactory(iface):
    """Load PluginBuilder class from file PluginBuilder.

    :param iface: A QGIS interface instance.
    :type iface: QgsInterface
    """
    from .plugin_builder import PluginBuilder
    return PluginBuilder(iface)
```

The `classFactory` function is a special method loaded at QGIS startup.

We see here it looks for the class `PluginBuilder` in the file `plugin_builder.py`.

In the `PluginBuilder` class definition, we look for the QGIS menu action :

```py
class PluginBuilder:
    """A QGIS plugin that allows you to build QGIS plugins."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
[...]
    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
        # Create action that will start plugin configuration
        self.action = QAction(
            QIcon(':/plugins/plugin_builder/icon.png'),
            'Plugin Builder', self.iface.mainWindow())
        # connect the action to the run method
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
[...]
```

The last line is the signal connection (callback) when the user clicks (or triggers) the menu action. It launch the method `self.run`.

So here you have two choices :

- create in your plugin a method / function that call `self.run`
- look in the `self.run` method what's going on and rewrite it in a method / function

First choice :

```py
def open_other_plugin(self):
    from pluginbuilder3.plugin_builder import PluginBuilder

    self.new_plugin = PluginBuilder(self.iface)
    self.new_plugin.run()

self.open_other_plugin()
```

Second choice :

```py
def open_other_plugin(self):
    from pluginbuilder3.plugin_builder_dialog import PluginBuilderDialog

    self.dialog = PluginBuilderDialog()
    self.dialog.setWindowTitle("My Builder Custom instance")
    self.dialog.show()

self.open_other_plugin()
```

We can also create a new dialog instance and return it (work in the two choices):

```py
def create_other_plugin(self):
    from pluginbuilder3.plugin_builder_dialog import PluginBuilderDialog

    dialog = PluginBuilderDialog()
    return dialog

self.other_plugin = self.create_other_plugin()
self.other_plugin.show()
```

---

**EDIT** : Test

I've created two plugins <kbd>plugin1</kbd> and <kbd>plugin2</kbd>.
In the plugin folder of the current QGIS user profile :

- plugin1

  - `__init__.py`
  - `metadata.txt`
- plugin2

  - `__init__.py`
  - `metadata.txt`

***First plugin, plugin1, that calls the second plugin***

See the comments in the `run` method.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox

def classFactory(iface):
    return FirstPlugin(iface)


class FirstPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.second_plugin = None

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QAction("One", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        del self.action

    def run(self):
        # import plugin2 SecondPlugin class like other modules
        from plugin2 import SecondPlugin
        # create a second plugin class instance
        self.second_plugin = SecondPlugin(self.iface)
        QMessageBox.information(None, "First plugin", "This is the run of the first plugin")
        # call second plugin instance run method
        self.second_plugin.run()
```

***Second plugin plugin2***

This is a classic plugin, no special code here.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QDialog, QMessageBox

def classFactory(iface):
    return SecondPlugin(iface)


class SecondPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.dlg = QDialog()

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QAction("Two", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        del self.action

    def run(self):
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Second plugin", "This is the run of the second plugin")
        self.dlg.show()
```

Comment: No wonder that you will answer, bounty (+50) and PyQt for you are like pollen for honeybees 

Comment: @J. Monticolo I tried your solution, but unfortunately can't get it to work. Would you agree to help me to solve the problem, because it is very important for me. (Zoom call, E-Mail ... ?)

Comment: Is your plugin standalone or under QGIS ?

Comment: It is in QGIS. sorry for my late replay, I didnt see your answer

Comment: @MoritzSproll: I will test it with 2 minimal plugins.

Comment: yes I also tried this, I created plugin "test" and plugin "test2"; but I am not getting it working. Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @J.Monticolo could you find out something ?

Comment: @MoritzSproll: 
I've been buzy these days, I will look for a solution maybe today ...

Comment: @J.Monticolo ok no problem, thank you !

Comment: @MoritzSproll: see my edit.

Comment: Yeah thank you ! It's working like that. But we want to call a dialog in the run-method of the second plugin with self.dlg.show(); But then we get an error: plugin2 object has no attribute 'dlg'. How can we tackle this issue ?

Comment: @MoritzSproll: I added a dialog in the example, hope that helps.

Comment: It's working; Thank you a lot !!

Answer (score -1):

First you need to check the plugin name in QGIS PYTHON console:

```
qgis.utils.plugins
```

In your plugin put this code:

```
import qgis        
secondPlugin = qgis.utils.plugins["PluginName"] # plugin instance
if secondPlugin
   secondPlugin.run() # Run plugin
```

Comment: Please provide detailed instructions with your answer.  Explain what your code does, why it's needed, and what to do after running your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, that `run` method doesn't run the plugin. It runs the `run` method if a `run` method exist in the plugin's root class. And you cannot be 100% sure if it exists. For example, QuickWKT plugin has no `run` method.